# TypeError with Python zip() after Select Statements to Generate Pairs

Tags: python, database, list, postgresql, typeerror

Here is my code to create a Swiss Pairing system that generates pairs of players for matches:

```
def swissPairings():
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=tournament")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("select PlayerID from Scores order by Wins;")
    ids = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("select Players.Name from Players join Scores\
        on Players.PlayerID = Scores.PlayerID\
        order by Wins;")
    names = c.fetchall()
    standings = playerStandings()
    pairs = zip(ids,names)
    print pairs
    db.close()
```

When I run the test for the actual pairing, I do get a list as follows (but it looks kind of funny, it should be generating two pairs as there are four players, but instead it's generating one long list):

```
[((291,), ('Fluttershy',)), ((293,), ('Pinkie Pie',)), ((290,),
('Twilight Sparkle',)), ((292,), ('Applejack',))]
```

But it is followed by the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rebecca/fullstack/vagrant/tournament/tournament_test.py", line 136, in <module>
    testPairings()
  File "/Users/Rebecca/fullstack/vagrant/tournament/tournament_test.py", line 116, in testPairings
    if len(pairings) != 2:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

How can I resolve this error? It seems like I have to append something, but I can't figure out what... I need to make len(pairings) == 2, which right now it seems to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

Each of your select statements yields a *list* of *tuples* with only one element, so the contents of `ids` and `names`are a list of tuples.

```
ids   => [(291,), (293,), (290,), (292),]
names => [ ('Fluttershy',), ('Pinkie Pie',), ('Twilight',), ('Applejack',) ]
```

The above means that `zip` will create a new list of tuples, where each *value-pair* will be a pair of *tuples* from *ids* and *names* respectively.

What you are looking for is to transform the data received from the database so that you get two list of values (not tuples) — in other words; you need to unpack the tuples before you invoke `zip`.

---

#### Proposed Solution

In order to fix the issue you simple need to make sure that both *ids* and *names* are a list of values, and not a list of tuples containing a single value.

Which can be done in an easy manner with any of the following alternatives:

```
ids   = [ x[0] for x in c.fetchall () ] # unpack tuples
```

```
...
```

```
names = [ x[0] for x in c.fetchall () ] # unpack tuples
```

---

#### Alternative solutions

Another syntax for yielding a list of the first elements of each tuple in a list of tuples:

```
ids = [ x for x, in c.fetchall () ]  # unpack tuple
```

You could of course also change your invocation of `zip` so that the unpacking takes place there (there's no need to change anything else if you go by this solution):

```
pairs = zip ([ x for x, in ids], [x for x, in names])
```

---

#### Circumventing the problem all together

Simply select both the *id*  and the *name* of the players at once:

```
c.execute("select Players.PlayerId, Player.Name from Players join Scores\
    on Players.PlayerID = Scores.PlayerID\
    order by Wins;")

pairs = c.fetchall ()
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you. With the unpacking, my list now generates as follows:  
   `[(381, 'Fluttershy'), (383, 'Pinkie Pie'), (380, 'Twilight Sparkle'), (382, 'Applejack')]`
  
How would I be able to get this two show two sets of pairs? Like so-  
    `[(381, 'Fluttershy'), (383, 'Pinkie Pie')],
    [(380, 'Twilight Sparkle'), (382, 'Applejack')]`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the traceback, the error originates in the *testPairings* function. Perhaps you could include the source code for it?

Without seeing it, I will venture that your error may be caused by *testPairings* calling *swissPairings* and expecting to receive a return value; but *swissPairings* doesn't return anything, it is printing the results instead. Try removing the `print pairs` line and adding `return pairs` below the call to `db.close()`.

As for your results structure, I think it would be easier, safer and more efficient to not use zip() and to produce the pairs with a single SQL query:

SELECT Players.PlayerID, Players.Name FROM Scores INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerID = Scores.PlayerID ORDER BY Scores.Wins

Finally, what does your call to *playerStandings()* do? You don't pass it any parameter, or receive any value from it. Is it printing another data set? If so, I would advise you to refactor it; it is generally best to split your functions in two: have some that obtain data (and do just that) and some that call those and print the results using the desired format. If you tie up your queries with their presentation, you are making it impossible to obtain data without printing it on screen, which reduces code reuse and makes your program harder to understand and maintain.